# MATLAB, overwriting in command window

Tags: matlab

I am running some code in MATLAB and basically there is a lot of output, that is going into the MATLAB command window.

However, when it gets so many thousand, it starts to overwrite, so the output at the very start disappears from the MATLAB command window?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you save your logs to a file? Or better yet, to several files according to the topic? Or even better - instead of printing text make some visualization/figure?  Or save some matrices as `.mat` files? Usually those who print massive amounts of text to the console are not aware of other options, this is why I mention this.

Comment: If your problem is that you don't want to lose that text (it's not clear from your question), the simplest solution is [`diary`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html), which will dump everrthing into a text file

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo I appreciate your thoughts on this, ideally I would like them in excel, then I can sort them out properly.

Comment: Dev-iL thanks I will look how to code better, I am new to this!

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar To import into Excel, see [`save`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) with the `'-ascii'` option, or [`dlmwrite`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html), or [`csvwrite`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html).